# How to add event listener to local react native notification

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification

**Goal**

I have setup a local notification schedule in my react native app for once an hour. I however want to implement a 'snooze zone' as I call it. I want a automated way to turn off the hourly notifications between hour A and hour B. (aka when someone is sleeping I don't want the notifications to fire)

**My Code**

First I set my local notification on a hourly schedule which works like a charm

```
PushNotificationIOS.scheduleLocalNotification({
  fireDate:Date.now(),
  alertBody:'Time to Track your Pain',
  repeatInterval:'hour',
});
```

Then I add my event listener

```
PushNotificationIOS.addEventListener('localNotification',this.checkSnoozeZone);
```

The checkSnoozeZone function

```
checkSnoozeZone = () => {
  //this is where I want to reschedule the notification based on snooze zone times
  console.log("Event fired");
}
```

**My Issue**

The function only fires after I open the notification. The documentation for [PushNotificationIOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html) states that it should work when the app is in foreground or background. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation states that one handler will be used for notifications, no matter state of application is foreground or background. Handle local notifications in iOS separates in two parts 1. notification itself 2. custom handler. In your case custom handler fires when application becomes foreground as it should do.
Think of using separate Scheduler for schedule and cancel local notification or schedule several daily notifications.